# Django - PermissionRequiredMixin - Return a 'permission_denied_message' in current View, instead of a 403 Page?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-3.0

```
Django version 3.0.5
```

I want to use the `PermissionRequiredMixin` in my View to display
a banner message the same way I would with the `SuccessMessageMixin`.

For example,  if a user attempts to delete an object and they do not have permissions,
the `permission_denied_message` would essentially be treated as an error message an
displayed in the current view as a banner message.

Is that even possible?

the code that I currently have does not work - it always redirects to the 403 page.
see below:

```
class DocDeleteView(PermissionRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, DeleteView):
    model = SlateDoc
    success_url = reverse_lazy('slatedoc-list')
    success_message = "SlateDoc was deleted!"

    permission_required = ('slatedoc.delete_slatedoc')
    raise_exception = True
    permission_denied_message = "Permission Denied"

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.has_permission() is False: 
            messages.error(self.request, self.permission_denied_message)
        else: 
            self.object = self.get_object()
            self.object.soft_delete()
            messages.success(self.request, self.success_message)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

=====================================================================

2021-10-07

So I've updated my code a bit, and now I can get the 'Permission Denied' Error message to show, but it still redirects to a 403 page.
So, I see a red error message across the top of a 403 page.
Still trying to figure out how to just have the error message show up
on the same View without the redirect to a 403 page.

```
class DocDeleteView(PermissionRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, DeleteView):
    model = SlateDoc
    success_url = reverse_lazy('slatedoc-list')
    success_message = "SlateDoc was deleted!"

    permission_required = ('slatedoc.delete_slatedoc')
    raise_exception = False
    permission_denied_message = "Permission Denied"

    def get_permission_denied_message(self):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        messages.error(self.request, self.permission_denied_message)
        return reverse('slatedoc-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        self.object.soft_delete()
        messages.success(self.request, self.success_message)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Comment: PermissionRequiredMixin either allows access or forbids it (403 status code). To achive your goal, skip using it in your view (as your are doing) - Do no forget to return a redirect or render after you added the error message.

Comment: Sorry, but I don’t understand - what do you mean by “skip using it” ? If I do not use the PermissonRequiredMixin, how do I know if the user has permissions to perform that action or access the view?

Answer (score 0):

for anyone interested:
here is the code I used to get this to work.
[@hendrikschneider](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1199807/hendrikschneider) was right - I needed to just remove the PermissionRequiredMixin

```
class DocDeleteView(SuccessMessageMixin, DeleteView):
    model = SlateDoc
    success_url = reverse_lazy('slatedoc-list')
    success_message = "SlateDoc was deleted!"

    permission_required = ('slatedoc.delete_slatedoc')
    permission_denied_message = "Permission Denied"

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.has_perm(permission_required):
            self.object = self.get_object()
            messages.error(self.request, self.permission_denied_message)
            return redirect(reverse('slatedoc-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk}))
        else:
            self.object = self.get_object()
            self.object.soft_delete()
            messages.success(self.request, self.success_message)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```